# What does the phrase "gone too far to brain" mean here?

Tags: meaning

The counter-revolution has set in. The ban on somatotonia is lifted, and if our grandchildren go to Sunday school they may be shown pictures not of a Christ suffering in cerebrotonic tight-lipped silence on a cross, but of a Christ performing heroic feats of athletic prowess ... Christianity has been in some sense a religious suppression of somatotonia, but we seem now to have come into a counter-revolution, with a tendency to hoot automobile horns and to amplify every kind of noise in general celebration. We have been on a somatotonic joy-ride. Possibly we were a degenerating race, **gone too far to brain**: the long period of cerebrotonic ratiocination which we call the Christian period might indicate as much. From such a point of view the recent somatotonic revolution, if such it really is, may be a sign of health, even though it be a regression to barbarism. From another point of view somatotonia in the ascendent may be a catastrophe. In any case, we may be sure of one thing: the appraisal put upon history will always depend upon which component pronounces the judgment.

Comment: Who wrote that frightful nonsense?

Comment: The exact sentence after this paragraph: One thinks one is dreaming when one reads such nonsense ... 

Comment: It's a translation from German to English, and I'm translating it to another language. But most of the time this text surprises me in wonderful ways...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an auto-translation from German, and the OP is asking what a translation of a German idiom means. They should seek advice on the meaning of the german idiom, and then perhaps seek help rendering that in English.

Comment: The idiom seems clear enough. It's the rest I don't like.

Comment: I think it's a ***machine*** translation. A real human being would almost certainly have translated *the appraisal put upon history will always depend upon which component  pronounces the judgment* as ***History is written by the winners.***

Comment: I've met people who talk like that.

Comment: And they aren't all Germans.

Comment: That's completely made up by the author or translator,  /but what a great turn of phrase/ it is!

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @ Astralbee  If you don't know how to answer a question, please stop "voting to close" it.

Answer (score 4):

We can use 'gone to seed' to discuss a plant which has been allowed to grow too long and has now produced seeds, dropped its leaves, stopped blooming, etc. "Gone to brain" sounds like an adaptation of that, by the writer, to describe the human race progressing too far in the process of preferring thinking (brain activity) over aggressive, extraverted physical activity.

Answer (score 3):

"Brain" seems to be used to mean "A state of favouring intellectual over physical skills"  This is a form of metonymy.

It is a figure of speech, invented by the writer.